# What is a command?

Tags: shell, command, terminology

Clear thinking and clear communication are facilitated when different terms are used to represent different concepts.

This is particularly useful when the 2 concepts are very similar but different.

We tend to use the term "command" to represent 2 very similar but different concepts.

**concept 1: A single program entered on a command-line interface.**

Options might be passed to the program, but there is still only 1 program being used.

example(s):

```
$ ls
$ ls -alF
```

This concept is referred to as a "command".

**concept 2: Anything entered on a command-line interface before hitting the Enter key to instruct the shell to process it.**

example(s):

```
$ ls -alF | head > output.txt; cat output.txt
```

This concept is also referred to as a "command".
This is true even though it contains 3 different "commands" according to the previous definition.

For people who desire to use different terms to represent different concepts in order to think and communicate ideas more precisely, what are the best terms to use to represent these 2 different concepts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I guess you could read the Shell Command Language specification, esp. [2.9 Shell Commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09).

> This section describes the basic structure of shell commands. The following command descriptions each describe a format of the command that is only used to aid the reader in recognizing the command type, and does not formally represent the syntax. [...] Each description discusses the semantics of the command; for a formal definition of the command language, consult [Shell Grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).
>
> A command is one of the following:
> [Simple command, Pipeline, List, Compound command, Function definition]

This, below, is a [simple command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), and `ls` here is the "command name":

```
ls -alF
```

This, below, is a [pipeline](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) with two simple commands in it:

```
ls -alF | head > output.txt
```

This, below, is a [sequential list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_04) (or just a [list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03)) of a pipeline and a simple command:

```
ls -alF | head > output.txt; cat output.txt
```

(Then again, you can take the very first example here also as a (degenerate) pipeline.)

And this, below, is a list with an AND-list containing a pipeline of a compound command and a simple command, with another simple command next in the list.

```
for x in a b c; do echo "$x"; done | cat -n && echo ok; echo end.
```

(And if I read the part on Lists correctly, if you separated the commands with a newline instead of a `;`, it'd be a compound list, but that's nitpicking already.)

I wouldn't really expect other documentation (or posts on this site) to carefully adhere to using those exact phrases (correctly), so trying to communicate using them precisely might turn out to be difficult. Embrace the chaos.

Comment: And `ls`, `head` etc. are “command names”.

Comment: This is perfect. The spec seems to discern the terms by using the term "shell command" to represent "the generic thing that gets processed by the shell as a single unit when we send it to the shell" and (2) using other terms to differentiate the various form that the shell command can take.

Answer (score 1):

I'll argue for there being (at least) 4 different concepts that're commonly called "commands". In order of increasing complexity:

1. A command name: the name (or path to) an executable program or script. For example, `ls`, `cat`, `/usr/libexec/bootpd`, etc.
2. A command name *and a list of arguments*. For example, `ls`, `-l`, and `/etc`. This corresponds to the arguments to [`execl()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) (except that the command name would be passed twice), and is what you can run with `find .. -exec` or `sudo` or most other contexts that run commands *without passing them through a shell*. Note that in this form, the arguments have no syntax at all, they're just strings, and it's up to the command executable to decide what they mean.

   (Note that when you run `find ... -exec` or `sudo`, the entire command is parsed by a shell, but that's the `find`/`sudo` command, not the command that `find` or `sudo` is going to run. This is why you can't include things like redirects in something run by `find` or `sudo`.)

   This one isn't often recognized, but IMO it's vital to understand it to make sense of situations where a command is being run by something other than a shell.
3. A simple shell command. This is a single string (unlike the last one, which was a list of separate strings) generally consisting of a command name and arguments (separated by whitespace), and maybe some additional things like redirects and/or environment variable assignments. It can include a variety of shell syntax, like quotes, variable substitutions, etc. For example: `ls -l /etc >"$outdir/etcfiles.list"`.

   This also includes some things that don't correspond to commands in the first two senses, like variable assignments (`var=something`), shell builtin commands, functions, aliases, and (depending on the shell) things like `[[ ]]` conditional expressions and `(( ))` arithmetic expressions.
4. Anything you can put on a single line in a shell. Technically, this can be categorized into pipelines, lists, compound commands, etc. As ilkkachu said, read the [Shell Command Language specification, section 2.9 Shell Commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09) for details.

I also agree with ilkkachu that there's no sense trying to develop or use a completely consistent terminology. Even if you could, most people using the terms wouldn't completely understand the distinctions, and they'd wind up getting muddled together in short order (consider the number of people who call all shells "bash"). You just need to figure it out from context.

Also, things can get a little weird anyway, for example `ls -l $(echo "$PATH" | tr : " ")` is a simple command that contains a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This question feels like it should be closed as an 'opinion' question, but I'll take a stab at an answer anyway.

First, I usually refer to the type of thing from your second concept as a "one-liner", though I will use the term "command" just as easily. This brings up my first opinion: your definition of the second concept is flawed, in that you can enter multiple commands before hitting 'Enter'. The `;` in your example separates two distinct commands. I don't consider that example to be one command, I consider it to be two commands. The pipe symbol unifies two commands into a single "command pipeline", that I still refer to and think of as a single command.

I would also argue that a 'command' can be a simple command, such as `ls`, or a compound command, such as a pipeline. As such, the term 'command' is valid in both cases.

In conclusion, I don't think there's enough difference in the concepts you've posted to truly warrant different terminology.